# Python as a Windows service: DLL load failed while importing _openssl

Tags: python-3.8

Using Python 3.8.
I have a module that imports pgpy for encryption\decryption.
When run manually, everything works as expected.
However, when it is called by a Python scheduler running as a Windows service, it constantly throws the error:
**DLL load failed while importing _openssl: The specified module could not be found.**

I've look at other solutions that talk about having the specific dlls in the DLL path, but that hasn't helped me.
libcrypto-1_1.dll, libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1.dll, and libssl-1_1-x64.dll are all located in the Python38\DLLs folder (and the Scripts folder also for some reason).

Again, the script runs correctly with no issue when run manually.  It's only when it's called by a  scheduler run under a Windows service that it fails.

Looking for any advice or clue as to what I might be able to do here.

Comment: In the windows services management console, try changing the log on account of the service to your user.

Comment: Good suggestion, but the service is already running under my credentials.

Answer (score 2):

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip uninstall pyopenssl cryptography

pip install pyopenssl cryptography

import openssl:

python -v -c 'from OpenSSL import SSL'

or

when the "pip" installations do not work, the "conda" installations work more stable.

conda update -c conda-forge --all -y

conda install conda-forge::pyopenssl

conda install conda-forge::cryptography

Comment: I got this error and tried a few things. install openssl light - doesn't work. Add conda\library\bin to the environment path, doesn't work. then ran the top three commands in this solution and it worked.